# ¿Cómo cambiar el estilo de un componente Angular pero en un selector?

Tags: html, css, angular

Tengo un componente1 en Angular, donde tienen un container con un estilo:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 75px auto 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 840px;
}
```

Ese componente lo llamo desde un selector a dos partes de mi pagina que tienen diferente componente

componente2:

```
<section>
    <app-componente1></app-componente1>
</section>
```

componente3:

```
<div>
    <app-componente1></app-componente1>
</div>
```

Lo que pasa es que en mi componente2 quiero modificar el container del componente1 para que se adapte al componente2, pero no quiero afectar al que esta en mi componente3.

**¿Existe alguna forma de cambiar el estilo de un componente desde donde esta su selector sin afectar a los demás selectores? o ¿Existe alguna otra alternativa para trabajar los estilos que busco en Angular?**

Comment: ya intentaste modificar la hoja de estilo del componente dos?

Comment: ahí tienes un artículo que te puede servir https://devsuhas.com/2023/07/09/style-child-components-from-parent-angular/

Answer (score -1):

Debes pensar en solo 2 componentes, uno Padre (quien contiene dentro el componente) y el Hijo (el componente contenido dentro), el componente hijo siempre tiene sus propios estilos, pero se pueden modificar desde el componente padre de dos maneras:

**La 1ra es la buena**, la recomendada, en la que el componente hijo toma los estilos delegados del componente padre mediante un `@Input()` esto hace que cada padre deba setear los estilos de su hijo:

```
//app-componente-hijo.ts
 import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
  
 @Component({
     selector: 'app-hijo',
     templateUrl: './app-hijo.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./app-hijo.component.scss']
 })
 export class HijoComponent {
  @Input() estilosHeredados: string;

 
 }



//app-hijo.component.html
 <section [class]="this.estilosHeredados">
   // contenido de componente hijo
 </section>
```

ahora desde el componente padre enviamos el input de estilos:

```
//app-padre.component.ts
@Component({
     selector: 'app-padre',
     templateUrl: './app-padre.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./app-padre.component.scss']
 })
 export class PadreComponent {
  //estilos mediante clases de una librería de CSS, para este ejemplo son Tailwind
  public estilosDesdePadre: string = "mt-2 inline-block align-baseline ..."

 
 }
 
//app-padre.component.html
<section>
   <app-hijo [estilosHeredados]="this.estilosDesdePadre">
   </app-hijo>
</section>
```

**La 2da es la No recomendada**, pero que en ocasiones (por prisa o complejidad de código viejo) es necesaria. Se usa un tag de Angular llamado `ng-Deep` para sobreescribir estilos dentro de componentes:

En la hoja de estilos del componente padre, (con sass y con css):

```
//app-padre.component.scss
:host ::ng-Deep app-hijo {
   .container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 100%;
        grid-template-rows: 10vh 90vh;
        margin: 0;
        //estilos y calses heredadas
    }
   
}

 //app-padre.component.css
 :host ::ng-Deep app-hijo .container {
    //mis estilos custom
 }
```

En el primer método también puedes usar `[style]` en lugar de `[class]` para setear directamente estilos, pero para mejor manejo recomiendo clases. En el segundo método Angular lleva años amenzando en retirar `ng-deep` por la mala practica de sobreescribir, pero traigo Apps legacys desde versión 12 hasta la actual 16 y aun sigue funcionando.

Comment: Estás seguro de que en el html se debe usar `this.estilosHeredados`?? No deberías usar `this` en el html. Por otro lado, solo estás pasándole una clase... eso no sirve absolutamente de nada si el componente al que se la pasas no la tiene ya definida en su css o la tienes en un estilo global. Estás suponiendo que solo quiere pasarle clases de bootstrap por ejemplo, lo cual no sería excesivamente práctico porque solo permitiría modificar el estilo del componente al que se lo aplicas y no a cualquier otro componente que cuelgue de él... es demasiado limitado como para ser útil

Comment: Por otro lado, es buena práctica limitar el `ng-deep` con un `:host` primero, para evitar que se sangren estilos tal como pasaría en tu ejemplo. Estarás machacando los estilos del componente `app-hijo` en el resto de usos que tenga en su aplicación, con lo cual se aplicarían también en el otro componente que instancie a `app-hijo` tras visitar el componente donde cargas ese ng-deep. Voto -1 porque esta respuesta provoca la inclusión de errores en la aplicación, **nunca** se debe usar `ng-deep` sin limitarlo tal como se hace en este ejemplo.

Comment: Lo del `:host` si es cierto... Pero en la solución 1 es evidente que la modificación es bajo clases, clases de librería o clases globales desde la app, al final también se comenta de requerirse poder usar [style] y darle estilos directamente, la propia Libreria de Angular material usa el sistema de clases bajo inputs para dar estilos a sus componentes... tu vienes a llamar inútil el sistema impulsado por los creadores del Framework... por este tipo de gente es que las personas optan por no brindar ayuda.

Comment: No llamo inútil al sistema, es útil cuando es útil. No está claro exactamente lo que pide el usuario, y aún así decidiste responderle indicándole que eso soluciona su problema. Si necesita personalizar de diferentes maneras múltiples contenedores, dime, cómo le ayudará tu solución nº 1? Si hay dudas, se añade un comentario, si la respuesta no está claro que sirva como solución al posible problema, no es correcta. Te recomiendo que intentes no tomarte como un ataque los comentarios que te pongan, estamos aquí para ayudar a la gente no para crear drama. Yo solo critiqué tu respuesta, no a ti.